# How To select Query

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table view named as `tes`.

```
    +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | id_oba       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | nama_obat    | varchar(120) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | satuan       | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | stok_awal    | int(5)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | persediaan   | int(5)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | nama_suplier | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | pemakaian    | int(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | tanggal      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When I execute:

```
select id_oba, nama_obat, satuan, stok_awal, sum(pemakaian) AS pemakaian, persediaan, 
from tes group by id_oba;
```

I get this result:

```
    +--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+
    | id_oba | nama_obat | satuan | stok_awal | pemakaian | persediaan |
    +--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+
    |      1 | Paramex   | Botol  |        30 |        40 |          5 |       
    |      2 | Oskadon   | Botol  |        30 |        41 |         27 |      
    |      3 | Lindon    | Botol  |        31 |        30 |          4 |      
    +--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

How can I modify my query to get the result like this?

```
    +--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+
    | id_oba | nama_obat | satuan | stok_awal | pemakaian | persediaan | total |
    +--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+
    |      1 | Paramex   | Botol  |        30 |        40 |          5 | 45    |      
    |      2 | Oskadon   | Botol  |        30 |        41 |         27 | 67    |
    |      3 | Lindon    | Botol  |        31 |        30 |          4 | 34    |
    +--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+
```

Please help me with my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Change like this

```
select id_oba, nama_obat, satuan, stok_awal, sum(pemakaian) AS pemakaian,
persediaan,(sum(pemakaian)+persediaan) as total from tes group by id_oba;
```

Comment: Thanks for solving problem